# App Store notifications regarding price drops?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore

I've placed a few apps on my Wish List in the (iOS) App Store.

Will I get some kind of automatic notification in case of a price drop? Or: Can I make it so, *without using a third party app*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it via the web site [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com). Sign up for a free account to get started.

While it can't read your Apple wish list, you can create a wish list on that site and it will notify you of price drops of your wish list items via email. It will also email you about updates for your wish list and your "My Apps" list. Personally I don't keep any apps in "My Apps" list, since Apple updates them for me every night on all of my devices.

I have no professional affiliation with this web site. I'm just a satisfied user.

---

Note: Checking "Notify me of price drops by E-mail" and unchecking "Share My Wishlist" on the `Wish List` page of AppShopper didn't seem to be "remembered" by the site (perhaps due to my browser settings), but it *does* work on the `My Profile` page.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure: the App Store itself won't give such notifications then?

Comment: Correct. There is no way I know of to get price change notifications directly from the app store. AppShopper is an awesome site. It even knows about the Mac App Store now, although prices over there seem to be more stable.